# pandas single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i looked at the previous posts on this topic but none helped

```
def trendFinder():
    uptrend = pd.DataFrame()
    counts = 0
    x = 0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        trendSlot = pd.DataFrame
        trendSlot = (df.loc[x+1:x+10])
        closeAvg = (sum(trendSlot[:]['Close'])/10)
        openAvg = (sum(trendSlot[:]['Open'])/10)
        if trendSlot.iloc[-1]['Close'] > closeAvg:
            print('close average: ',closeAvg)
            print('open average:  ',openAvg)
            print(trendSlot)
            sleep(0.1)
            clear_output()
            counts +=1
        x+=10
    print(counts)
```

what basically happens here is that in each iteration, a mini-dataframe is created having rows/cols of the original `df`. then for mini-dataframe, if the close of the last line is larger than the average of all closes, that mini-dataframe is printed. the function runs smoothly for a while (i presume until the final iteration) until something happens which produces this error:

```
---> 12         if trendSlot.iloc[-1]['Close'] > closeAvg:
...
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a condition to the `if` statement like:

```
if (len(trendSlot) > 0) and (trendSlot.iloc[-1]['Close'] > closeAvg):
```

It should avoid attempt doing the failing `trendSlot.iloc[-1]` in case it's empty.